# Remote code integrity checking prior to execution

Tags: hacking, certificate

I'm contemplating putting a site online that could be an attractive target for hackers or  employees of the host, who could alter the site's code to their benefit.

Not wishing to self-host, I was thinking of SSH'ing into the host, uploading an md5 executable and ensuring the md5 over the site's code is as expected.

But of course, the code could be altered and reverted back between my scans.

I could automate the md5 over SSH so the window for modification substantially narrows, but ideally I'd like the code to be md5'd every time a visitor uses it, voiding the information given to the visitor if tampering has occurred.

I just can't put such an integrity check in the code online as it could be hacked out. Also, is the code I'm seeing in a secure shell the same as being served to a visitor...

Are there any recognized methods of remote code integrity checking prior to execution?

All the info I've read on code-signing tends to be during deployment or download.

Comment: who's got access to this host? using which account(s)? make the executable read-only, owned by root and readable and executable by the intended user and set its immutable attribute. All of this if futile if the server is not properly hardened.

Comment: Consider it is cloud hosted, say Heroku, Google, etc. Is employee access to hosted code impossible, forbidden or in-confidence?

Answer (score 3):

Checking the integrity of the site every time it is accessed seems like an odd way to approach this.

I'd recommend you use a [file integrity monitoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_integrity_monitoring) system, which would check your site against a 'known-good' baseline. These will go much further than simple MD5 checking - they typically use much stronger hashes, such as SHA-256, and will check attributes, security properties etc too. Integrity checks can be automated, and you can schedule them to run at short intervals. Any good ones will also come with alerting capabilities.

If you're using Linux, look into [Tripwire](http://www.tripwire.org). If you're on Windows, consider something like [Ionx Verisys](http://www.ionx.co.uk).

You should also ensure the server is [hardened](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardening_%28computing%29) appropriately. How you go about this will depend on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Tripwire can check for differences in files: http://www.tripwire.org/

Hosted code should in practice *never* be modifiable live. To deploy, use a version control system so any changes can be tracked to a specific person. Then during deployment you can lock down the site's files so they're unable to modified.

If you're really worried about  a host compromising your data or application, then I'd look for another host.